# VS2017 / VS2019 - SQL Server database project - joining to user-defined table type breaks schema validation

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

- Using Visual Studio 2017/2019 (latest updates)
- SQL Server Database Project (created a brand new one to test)
- Targeting Azure SQL Database V12

[I reported this issue to Microsoft (for those following the trail)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/845925/database-schema-validation-fails-when-joining-on-a.html)

We have noticed that when joining on a user-defined table type (UDTT) in Visual Studio, schema validation for the script is disabled.  So if there is a mis-typed column name, for example, the build (locally or on the Azure DevOps build server) does not catch the error.

> Here is a complete example that illustrates this issue

```
create table dbo.RealTable (RealColumn int not null); 
go

create type dbo.TableOfNVarchar20 as table (Value nvarchar(20) not null);
go

create procedure dbo.usp_ProcReferencingMissingColumn 
    @tableOf20 dbo.TableOfNVarchar20 readonly
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    select   top (1)
             rt.MissingColumn
    from     dbo.RealTable rt

    -- this join breaks all (column level) schema validation in Visual Studio
    join     @tableOf20 ou on ou.Value = rt.RealColumn

    where    rt.MissingColumn > getdate()
    order by rt.MissingColumn desc;
end;
```

In this case, the table "RealTable" was modified and a column "MissingColumn" was removed. The build did not fail even though "MissingColumn" was still being referenced.

While trying to find out why the builds were not breaking, **I found out that *commenting out the join to the UDTT* restored schema validation on the builds and also in the IDE!**

> **Is it possible to fix this?**  Validation works as expected if I copy the above script into SSMS.

Screen shots to illustrate behavior

- [No errors when the join is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2ONo.png)
- [Errors show up when the join is removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soJgx.png)
- [Validation works (even with the join) in SSMS v17.9.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAkB8.png)

Comment: I  think in the VS schema validation only get implemented when there is join. Remember SSMS is different from sql db Project in VS2019.